# Why doesn't my react function return the proper html codes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a follow-up question to my SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69995862/why-does-my-function-run-before-componentdidmount). The accepted answer did resolve my problem. However I wound up with all `Categories` listed under the main menu. I determined it was because I was calling a `push` in the middle of a `push`.

Original relevant code:

```
function AddMenu(category) {
    if (category.children.length !== 0) {
        categoriesStyled.push(<SubMenu label={category.name}>
        { category.children.forEach(element => AddMenu(element) )}
        </SubMenu>);
    }
    else {
        categoriesStyled.push(<MenuItem>{category.name}</MenuItem>);
    }
}
```

I tried to fix this by splitting my function into two:

```
function AddSubMenu(category) {
    if (category.children.length !== 0) {
        return (<SubMenu label={category.name}>
            {category.children.forEach((catchild) => AddSubMenu(catchild))}
            </SubMenu>);
    }
    else {
        return (<MenuItem>{category.name}</MenuItem>);
    }
}

function AddMenu(category) {            
    if (category.children.length !== 0) {                
        categoriesStyled.push(<SubMenu label={category.name}>
            {category.children.forEach((catchild) => AddSubMenu(catchild))}
        </SubMenu>);
    }
    else {
        categoriesStyled.push(<MenuItem>{category.name}</MenuItem>);
    }
}
```

This shows all the main (First level) `Categories` but nothing under each `SubMenu` when the category has children. Why can't I return sub-items? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It might be worth looking into using `.map()` instead of `.forEach()` and pushing to an array.

Comment: I think you have to check `AddMenu` function, forEach doesn't return anything so they won't have any submenu items from calling `AddSubMenu` inside `forEach`.

Comment: @DBS switching to `map()` fixed my problem. Thanks! Do you want to put that in an answer?